# Cómo integrar un ejecutable en una GUI con PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Tengo un ejecutable que me gustaría integrar en mi interfaz. Por el momento tengo que se pueda ejecutar con un botón pero la ventana de la consola de comandos con la ejecución me gustaría poder integrarla en mi interfaz.

He probado una solución que hay en inglés pero no me ha funcionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474647/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-python-gui-pyqt

Código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import subprocess, time, win32gui, csv, os
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

"""
#names: b   - button
        tb  - toolbar 
        lb  - label
"""
# main window
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.iniUI()

    # init main window
    def iniUI(self):
        # dimensions
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 175, 500, 350))
        self.setWindowTitle("SIM_DDWs")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
        self.center()

        # methods
        self.menu()

        # buttons
        """
        # button load configuration
        bLoadConfig = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Load Configuration', self)
        bLoadConfig.resize(bLoadConfig.minimumSizeHint())
        bLoadConfig.move(370, 210)
        QtWidgets.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        bLoadConfig.setToolTip('Load an existing configuration for the simulator')
        """
        # button view results
        bViewResult = QtWidgets.QPushButton('View Results', self)
        bViewResult.clicked.connect(self.openNewWindowPlot)
        bViewResult.resize(bViewResult.minimumSizeHint())
        bViewResult.move(370, 255)
        QtWidgets.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        bViewResult.setToolTip('View the results')

        # button exit
        bExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Exit", self)
        bExit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        bExit.resize(bViewResult.minimumSizeHint())
        bExit.move(370, 300)
        QtWidgets.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        bExit.setToolTip('Exit the app and go to the desktop')

        #button run
        bRun = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self)
        bRun.clicked.connect(self.runExe)
        bRun.resize(bViewResult.minimumSizeHint())
        bRun.move(370, 210)
        QtWidgets.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        bRun.setToolTip('Run de app')
        bRun.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('run.png'))

        """
        # button built configuration
        bBuiltConfig = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Built Configuration', self)
        bBuiltConfig.resize(bLoadConfig.minimumSizeHint())
        bBuiltConfig.move(370, 125)
        QtWidgets.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        bBuiltConfig.setToolTip('Built a new configuration for the simulator')
        """
        # display app
        self.show()

    # menu
    def menu(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        tbFile = mainMenu.addMenu('File')

        # add run to toolbar
        tbRun = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('run.png'), 'Run', self)
        tbRun.setShortcut('F5')
        tbRun.setStatusTip('Run')
        tbRun.triggered.connect(self.runExe)
        tbFile.addAction(tbRun)
        """
        # add built config to toolbar
        tbBuilt = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('built.png'),'Built Configuration', self)
        tbFile.addAction(tbBuilt)

        # add load config to toolbar
        tbLoad = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('load.png'), 'Load Configuration', self)
        tbFile.addAction(tbLoad)
        """
        # add view results to toolbar
        tbView = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('results.png'), 'View Results', self)
        tbView.triggered.connect(self.openNewWindowPlot)
        tbFile.addAction(tbView)

        # add exit to toolbar
        tbExit = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        tbExit.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        tbExit.setStatusTip('Exit')
        tbExit.triggered.connect(self.close)
        tbFile.addAction(tbExit)

        # add editor to toolbar
        tbEditor = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('editor.png'), 'Editor', self)
        tbEditor.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
        tbEditor.setStatusTip('Editor')
        tbEditor.triggered.connect(self.openNewWindow)
        editorMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('Editor')
        editorMenu.addAction(tbEditor)

        # add help to toolbar
        tbHelp = mainMenu.addMenu('Help')
        tbHelp2 = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('help.png'), 'Help', self)
        tbHelp2.setStatusTip('Help')
        tbHelp2.triggered.connect(self.close)
        tbHelp.addAction(tbHelp2)

        # add about to toolbar
        tbAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('about.png'), 'About', self)
        tbAbout.setStatusTip('About')
        tbAbout.triggered.connect(self.helpWindow)
        tbHelp.addAction(tbAbout)

    # help window
    def helpWindow(self):
        widget = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        widget.setWindowTitle('About')
        widget.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('about.png'))
        widget.exec_()
        widget.show()

    # question if you want to close it or not
    def closeEvent(self, event):

        reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit', "Are you sure you want to exit the application?",
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No,
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    # center the app
    def center(self):
        cent = self.frameGeometry()
        center = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        cent.moveCenter(center)
        self.move(cent.topLeft())

    # open new window
    def openNewWindow(self):
        self.neww = newWindow()
        self.neww.show()

    def openNewWindowPlot(self):
        self.newWindowPlot = newPlotWindow()
        self.newWindowPlot.show()

    # run the main program in C++
    def runExe(self):

        exePath = ('main.exe')
        subprocess.Popen(exePath)
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, "mainFrame", 'main.exe')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        window = QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd)
        self.createWindowContainer(window, self)
        self.setGeometry(350, 175, 500, 350)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Main')
        window.show()

class newPlotWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(newPlotWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(600, 600, 1000, 600)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Results')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('results.png'))
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.readCSV)

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.main_widget.setLayout(layout)

    # center the app
    def center(self):
        cent = self.frameGeometry()
        center = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        cent.moveCenter(center)
        self.move(cent.topLeft())

    # read csv file generated by main and print the plot
    def readCSV(self):
        with open('resultado.csv') as csvFile:
            try:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
                toa, frecIni = [], []
                for row in reader:
                    # print(row["TOA (ns)"], row["Frecuencia Inicial (MHz)"])
                    toa.append(row["TOA (ns)"])
                    frecIni.append(row["Frecuencia Inicial (MHz)"])
                ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
                ax.clear()
                toaf = [float(i) for i in toa]
                frecInif = [float(i) for i in frecIni]
                ax.plot(toaf, frecInif, "ro")
                ax.set_xlabel('TOA (ns)')
                ax.set_ylabel('Frecuencia Inicial (MHz)')
                self.canvas.draw()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:", e)

    # new window
    class newWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(newWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initnewUI()

    #init new window
    def initnewUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Editor')
        self.setGeometry(300, 150, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('editor.png'))
        self.menunew()
        self.editorText()
        self.center()

    # menu for new window
    def menunew(self):
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')

        # add open file to toolbar
        tbOpenFile = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('openfile.png'), 'Open File', self)
        tbOpenFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        tbOpenFile.setStatusTip('Open File')
        tbOpenFile.triggered.connect(self.fileOpen)
        fileMenu.addAction(tbOpenFile)

        # add save file to toolbar
        tbSaveFile = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('savefile.png'), 'Save File', self)
        tbSaveFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+G')
        tbSaveFile.setStatusTip('Save File')
        tbSaveFile.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)
        fileMenu.addAction(tbSaveFile)

    # open new file
    def fileOpen(self):
        nombre, ok = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')
        if ok:
            file = open(nombre, 'r')

            self.editorText()
            with file:
                text = file.read()
                self.textEdit.setText(text)

    # save file
    def saveFile(self):
            name, ok = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File')
            if ok:
                file = open(name, 'w')
                text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
                file.write(text)
                file.close()

    # center new window
    def center(self):
        cent = self.frameGeometry()
        center = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        cent.moveCenter(center)
        self.move(cent.topLeft())

    # text editor
    def editorText(self):
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Preguntas en ambos lados :), podrias mostrar el codigo que no te ha funcionado para ver donde esta el problema

Comment: Por si acaso alguien que no sepa inglés puede ayudarme! Ya he editado el post.

Comment: que valor obtienes en `hwnd`?

Comment: es el window handle verdad? Window Handle: 00180812

Comment: podrias mostrar tu codigo completo, quizas lo este llamando en un parte incorrecta, prueba con `window.show()`

Comment: no es un código muy extenso pero sí son unas 300 líneas de código, igual no es muy legible subirlo así ¿cómo lo hago? ¿lo subo a algún sitio y pongo el enlace?

Comment: lee el siguiente post: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3558/c%C3%B3mo-pongo-el-c%C3%B3digo-en-las-preguntas-de-stackoverflow, alli te indica como colocar codigo

Comment: vale ya he añadido el código, es el botón "run" el que llama a la función "runExe".